# Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am usign codeigniter and I have hosted my web site on free hosting and everything was fine until an error occurred. The error is

```
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 346
```

But if I refresh the page the error is gone, but sometimes comes again and I don't why.

I have checked the forum for other errors like this and I have found that first I need to debug to understand what the error is.

It shows

```
Connecting to database: database_name
Connected OK:file: /home/vol11_6/byethost7.com/database_name/htdocs/application/config/database.php    Line: 81
```

Other users say that the error comes from php.ini or mysql.default_socket was pointing to file in a non-existent directory.

My question is how am I supposed to find this php.ini or the directory like /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
 on the free hosting. I can't find none of them.

Sorry if something was unclear.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "unable to connect" is a pretty generic message. you'd have to dig around for more details first. an answer telling you how/where to get  the location of mysql.sock would be utterly useless if the problem turns out to be a typo in the password.

Comment: The error: Message: mysql_connect(): Connection refused

Comment: then something is wrong at the network level, and the client is unable to connect to the server at all.